# Why QStandardItemModel 's member function children().size()return 0,while function hasChildren() return true?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

`_inputfileModel` is a pointer of type `QStandardItemModel`, I want to use its member function `children()` to get children items. But in the following codes,
`int childrenNum = _inputfileModel->children().size();`  `childrenNum`'s result is not 1 but 0. But when i use `hasChildren()`, the return value is true. Can anyone explain why? And does function `children()` returns toplevel children or all children?

```
void InputTree::addTreeNode(TreeNode &node){  

    QStringList inputImgList = node.picturePathList;  
    int num = inputImgList.size();  
    if( num < 1){ return ;}  
    QStandardItem *fatherItem = new QStandardItem;  
    fatherItem->setIcon(node.fatherIcon);  
    fatherItem->setText(node.fatherNodeName);  
    fatherItem->setData(FOLDER,ItemTypeRole);  

    for( int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        QStandardItem *pictureItem = new QStandardItem;
        pictureItem->setText(node.imageNodeName.at(i));
        pictureItem->setIcon(node.imgIcon);
        pictureItem->setData(PICTURE,ItemTypeRole);
        fatherItem->appendRow(pictureItem);
    }
    _inputfileModel->appendRow(fatherItem);
    bool has_child  = false;
    has_child = _inputfileModel->hasChildren();
    int childrenNum = _inputfileModel->children().size();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just read documentation:

> bool QAbstractItemModel::hasChildren(const QModelIndex & parent =
>   QModelIndex()) const
>
> Returns true if parent has any children; otherwise returns false.
>
> Use rowCount() on the parent to find out the number of children.

And what about children:

> const QObjectList & QObject::children() const
>
> Returns a list of child objects.

This is not you actually want.

So you should use `QStandardItemModel::rowCount` instead of `children()`;